# c# program stops responding "randomly"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program that looks for black tiles in the "Don't step on the white blocks" game and moves the mouse there. This all works. 
(I know my code and way of doing it is not the best)

But after a few seconds of the program working as intended, it stops responding (seen from task manager)

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
        private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
        //Mouse actions
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

        public void DoMouseClick()
        {
            //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
            uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
            uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void Btn_start_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

            int h = 850;
            int w;
            for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
            {
                w = 980;
                Color x = bitmap.GetPixel(w, h);
                do
                {
                    if (w > 1900) { w = 980; };
                    x = bitmap.GetPixel(w, h);
                    w += 3;
                } while (!(x.R == 0 && x.G == 0 && x.B == 0));

                await Task.Delay(50);
                Cursor.Position = new Point(w, h);
                //DoMouseClick();
                bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
                Debug.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

If any further information is required plase tell me! I'm a big noobie trying to learn.

Comment: WinForms has mouse support.  Why are you pinvoking and using threads?

Comment: Note that "not responding" is often code for "something you did is blocking the UI thread"

Comment: You use `h` for the y-Coordinate, but never chage it in your code.

Comment: You can pause the code (Break All) in the debugger to see where it got stuck. `while (!(x.R == 0 && x.G == 0 && x.B == 0))` might run forever if it does not find a black pixel.